# Express JS unable to PUT/DELETE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Project structure

```
.app.js
.routes/
....resources.js
```

I have the following server instance running:

*app.js*

```
"use strict";
const app = require('express')();
const resources = require('./routes/resources');

app.use('/', resources);

const server = app.listen('3000', () => {
  let host = server.address().address;
  host = (host == '::' ? 'localhost' : host);
  const port = server.address().port;
  // log it
  console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I have the GET and POST requests working (routes/resources.js) fine i.e.

```
"use strict"
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//parser
router.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
// data
let resources = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Foo'
}];

// POST
router.post('/resources', (req, res) => {
  let item = req.body;
  //send status
  if (!item.id) {
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  // saved as a string, id must be int
  item.id = parseInt(item.id, 10);
  // add id
  resources.push(item);
  // send the response of new resource
  res.send('/resources/' + parseInt(item.id, 10));
});
```

Using Postman I can successfully post, however the following PUT and DELETE 
give me the *Cannot DELETE /resources/* message:

```
// PUT
router.put('/resources/:id', (req, res) => {
  // get id from request
  let id = parseInt(req.body.id, 10);
  // find existing id in resources
  let existingItem = resources.filter(r => r.id === id)[0];
  // if it doesn't exist
  if(!existingItem) {
    let item = req.body;
    item.id = id;
    resources.push(item);
    res.setHeader('Location', '/resources/' + id);
    res.sendStatus(201)
  } else {
    existingItem.name = req.body.name;
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});
// DELETE
router.delete('/resources/:id', (req, res) => {
  let id = parseInt(req.body.id, 10);
  let existingItem = resources.filter(r => r.id === id)[0];

  if (!existingItem) {
    return res.sendStatus(404)
  }
  resources = resources.filter(r => r.id !== id);
  res.sendStatus(204)
});
```

Head scratching as to why, though it may be that the answer is staring me in the face. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to log req.method and req.url to see if it is as expected. So add app.use(function(req,res,next){console.log(req.method,req.url); next();}); before app.use('/', resources); to log requests and another app.use (can be same as the previous) bellow app.use('/', resources); to catch unhandled requests.

Comment: logoutput :DELETE /resources/
DELETE /resources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, I gave the DELETE and PUT paths the /:id parameter

```
router.delete('/resources/:id...)

router.put('/resources/:id'...)
```

when I was merely pointing the DELETE / PUT requests to '/resources/ inside POSTMAN.

Thanks for the help @Molda - made me realise my mistake!